# What is this crashed WW2 era aircraft?

Tags: military, aviation-history, aircraft-identification

There is a post D-Day Nazi propaganda film (with contemporary Allied narration) available on [YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pLJ-3T7K9rE). It shows a destroyed aircraft at 11:50, presumably Allied.

It looks like a twin-engine aircraft, although there may be a buckled propeller in front of the cockpit.

[image: Unknown crashed aircraft]
[source](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pLJ-3T7K9rE)

Answer (score 49, accepted):

It looks like a four engine bomber lying on its back. The air intakes on the leading edge leads me to believe it is a B-17.

I have inverted a couple of B-17 photos for reference:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Yes it's absolutely a B-17. Nice work!  I didn't know B17s had inverted flight capability!  Oh wait...

Comment: Ah yes, what I thought was the cockpit is a wheel. Good work!

Comment: @JohnK Every plane can fly inverted *once...*

Comment: You can fly any airplane inverted if you want, just not with the engines running in most cases.

Comment: “I didn't know B17s had inverted flight capability!” This plane isn’t flying; it has crashed.

Comment: @JohnK It depends on the carburetor. At least some versions of the Spitfire had a float carburetor that resulted in the engine cutting out if flying inverted.

Comment: @Davidw Also depends on the fuel system. Many aircraft that weren't designed for inverted flight have gravity-fed fuel systems. Those don't work well in inverted flight.

Comment: Could you shut the engines off at a high enough airspeed, fly inverted for a bit, turn back upright, and get them restarted? Or would the airframe not even survive the two half-rolls?

Comment: @Sixtyfive Two things: inverted doesn't necessarily mean negative G-force. Only the latter would be a problem for certain systems if sustained to long. The engines would simply restart by themselves once the get fed fuel again after a neg G cut out. And the other one: the airframe has to survive random turbulence - those cause higher stress then a well controlled half-roll. (Also consider the safety margins the anticipated random holes demand!)

Comment: In the southern emisphere sky and sea are inverted..problem solved

Comment: @Sixtyfive https://youtu.be/3IV9PZW1N9U  The quality of the digitization isn't that great, but if a 707 can do it...